# Install ModSecurity Commercial Rules

Tags: linux, security

We bought the ModSecurity commercial rules, but I am not having success installing them.  I tried using the ModSecurity dashboard, but it seems that it is not working.

Even though I get a message that the rules are loaded:

Wed Mar 09 18:51:52 2016] [notice] ModSecurity: Loaded 29647 rules from: 'https://dashboard.modsecurity.org/rules/download/plain'

I do not see them anywhere.

I removed all the free rules from the modsecurity.d directory (including the base_rules).

How can I get the commercial rules installed?

Answer (score 0):

You should have receive a license key with download instructions. [Documentation from the modsecurity.org website](https://www.modsecurity.org/commercial-rules.html):

> **How do I use the rules feed from Trustwave?**
>
> Once you purchase the ModSecurity Rules feed, you will receive the following information:
>
> - Unique license key(s). Use this key to identify yourself.
> - Download instructions. Details on using SecRemoteRules with your license key to pull the rules from the commercial rules repository.
> - Dashboard access. Choose which rules you want to support for a given license and see information about your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need license key to load ModSecurity rules with SecRemoteRules:

https://malware.expert/quick-install-guide/